# GSON - updating .json file

Tags: java, gson

Is there any way to update a value in JSON file without loading the file into object, changing the value and saving again?
It sounds very inefficient

EDIT:
E.g. I want to add an item into some array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution to this problem requires reading through the entire file in some manner.  Any off-the-shelf JSON library such as Gson will create objects to represent the textual JSON elements.

To avoid the "overhead" of creating the objects you could create a special-use parser but you'll still need to read the entire file.  You could reduce the amount of memory used by successively reading one line, processing it and then writing it to the output file.  In the case you describe this will mostly be writing the line back out with not changes.  This will be more efficient but may take a while to implement and may be buggy until you get them all worked out.  On top of that, if the JSON format changes you may have to change your code and then go through the process of working out the bugs you may have introduced.

If you don't want to write your own parser but the JSON file is large and you don't want to read it all into memory at once, you might check out Gson streaming: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming.

These days, people often use off-the-shelf libraries because they can get the implementation done faster and with fewer bugs, even though it is less efficient when it executes.  Unless the inefficiency has a measurable impact on user experience or noticeably affects execution time/memory utilization this practice is probably acceptable, but ymmv.